# Unity, how to access correct declaration in the API?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been using the Physics2D circle cast and taking a look at the documentation, https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.CircleCast.html , there are 3 declarations of the same name, and the third one fits my needs best, how do I use this one rather than the first one?

```
Physics2D.CircleCast(transform.position, radius, Vector2.up, ContactFilter2D.NoFilter, colliders, 0f);
```

This is what I have so far and it is giving me a compiler error saying that the contact filter needs to be an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about are [**Overloads**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/member-overloading).

An overloaded method means you have multiple versions with **same name** but **different signatures**.

=> **You don't** actively decide which overload you use!

The **compiler itself** figures out which parameters of which types you provide in which order and **automatically** uses the method overload with the **signature that best fits** the given parameters.

So if you write

```
Physics2D.CircleCast(transform.position, radius, Vector2.up, new ContactFilter2D().NoFilter(), colliders, 0f);
```

it will automatically use the overload with signature (if your `colliders` is a `List<RaycastHit2D>`)

```
Physics2D.CircleCast(Vector2, float, Vector2, ContactFilter2D, List<RaycastHit2D>, float);
```

or accordingly (if your `colliders` is a `RaycastHit2[]`)

```
Physics2D.CircleCast(Vector2, float, Vector2, ContactFilter2D, RaycastHit2D[], float);
```

Comment: This seems to have worked! The issue seems to have been that I was using ContactFilter2D.NoFilter inside the function call rather than assigning a ContactFIlter2D variable and then using that in the function. Can't seem to get my filter working though, it says that it needs an object reference. :/

Comment: Looks like it rather expects something like `Physics2D.CircleCast(transform.position, radius, Vector2.up, new ContactFilter2D().NoFilter(), colliders, 0f);`

Comment: GREAT, that worked, can't believe all I was missing was a "new", thanks for the help!